# how to have terminal look for .sh files in a folder other than pwd?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I would like to run ".sh" files in a directory without having to navigate to that directory, as shown below.

Me trying to run a .sh file, that is not in my current directory:

```
root@naveen-hp:/home# bash start-master.sh
bash: start-master.sh: No such file or directory
```

Me trying to run a .sh file by specifying it's location:

```
root@naveen-hp:/home# bash /usr/local/bin/spark/sbin/start-master.sh
starting org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master, logging to /usr/local/bin/spark/logs/spark-root-org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-naveen-hp.out
```

So, is there a way to have terminal to also look in `/usr/local/bin/spark/sbin/` directory, not just the pwd, when a request to run a .sh file is sent?

Comment: variable $PWD will have the *present working directory*

Comment: yes, pwd will have present working directory. I want bash to look also inside `/usr/local/bin/spark/sbin` whenever i run a .sh file.

Comment: You will first need to get out of the habit of running scripts with `bash` (or `sh`, or `csh`, or ...) explicitly - it's the job of the *shebang* to decide what interpreter to use. Once you make the script executable, THEN you can add `/usr/local/bin/spark/sbin/` to your `PATH`. The shell only searches your path for *programs*, not for *arguments to* programs - which is what you use `bash` explicitly.

Comment: sure @steeldriver. I haven't been able to add that directory to my path. i have copy-pasted many scripts from internet, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the path you want to contain the script file(s) to you PATH variable.

Look here for example: [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-the-path)